# Timestamp converter not working in Spring Data Rest with Spanner

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to convert the input timestamp which will be in the string format to cloud timestamp with the help of a Spring Data Rest custom converter which is not working. Need an help on the same in understanding why custom converters are not invoked.

Input: http://localhost:8080/apipromocentral/promotions
RequestBody : {"startDateTime": "2019-11-07 15:53:00"}

```
POJO:
@ApiModel
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "PROMOTIONS")
public class Promotion {
  /**
   * promotion id
   */
  @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Id of the Promotion", required = true)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column(name = "PROMO_ID")
  private String promotionId;

  @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Start Date Time of a promotion", allowableValues="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", required = true)
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  @Column(name = "START_DATE_TIME")
  private Timestamp startDateTime; //java.sql.timestamp;

}

converter code
@Component
public class TimestampWriteConverter implements Converter<java.sql.Timestamp, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convert(java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        //Return com.google.cloud.Timestamp;
        return Timestamp.of(sqlTimestamp);
    }
}
```

exception
"message": "FAILED_PRECONDITION: com.google.api.gax.rpc.FailedPreconditionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Invalid value for column START_DATE_TIME in table PROMOTIONS: Expected TIMESTAMP.",
        "trace": "com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: com.google.api.gax.rpc.FailedPreconditionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Invalid value for column START_DATE_TIME in table PROMOTIONS: Expected TIMESTAMP.\r\n\tat com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerExceptionPreformatted(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:156)\r\n\tat com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerException(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:45)\r\n\tat com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerException(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:112)\r\n\tat

Comment: QQ:  Have you passed this Converter to a ConverterAwareMappingSpannerEntityProcessor, which then has to be made available as a @Bean for SpannerEntityProcessor? See 13.2.10 of https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/_spring_data_cloud_spanner.html

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, looks like you need pass the TimestampWriteConverter converter to ConverterAwareMappingSpannerEntityProcessor.

```
@Configuration
public class ConverterConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SpannerEntityProcessor spannerEntityProcessor(SpannerMappingContext spannerMappingContext) {
        return new ConverterAwareMappingSpannerEntityProcessor(spannerMappingContext,
                Arrays.asList(new TimestampWriteConverter()),
                Arrays.asList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Fuad Malikov, I did register both reader and writer for the timestamp converter, it didn't work. I also tried marking start_date_time as a String and tried with the String to cloud timestamp and cloud timestamp to String converter which didn't work as well.

Comment: However one additional input I would like to give here : POJO to a String and String to a POJO is working fine without any issues. But here String to Timestamp or sql.Timestamp to cloud.Timestamp converter is not working.

Comment: Thanks, @GopalGowda, for the input. I have escalated this internally and looks like it might be a bug. We are currently working on it. Please stay tuned.

Comment: This has been now fixed in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/pull/2065. Please try 1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. We will also apply the fix to the 1.2.x branch.