# How to override one of the default Spanner converters in Spring Cloud GCP

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-spanner, spring-cloud-gcp

I use `spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner` for fetching data from GCP Spanner. One of my tables contains the TIMESTAMP column, which contains date-time in UTC.

Spring Data Cloud Data already has [some default Spanner converters](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/6058a68dcefc2ac67afafd06b2e0937d7a348e29/spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/data/spanner/core/convert/SpannerConverters.java#L252) for some custom types. My entity class maps TIMESTAMP (`com.google.cloud.Timestamp`) column to LocalDateTime.

It uses default [TIMESTAMP_LOCAL_DATE_TIME_CONVERTER](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/6058a68dcefc2ac67afafd06b2e0937d7a348e29/spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/data/spanner/core/convert/SpannerConverters.java#L129) and converts date-time according to my local zone (UTC+3). I added my custom converter and specified it using `ConverterAwareMappingSpannerEntityProcessor`, but my custom converter isn't used and appears at the end of the converters list (GenericConversionService#converters).

```java
public class LocalDateTimeReadConverter implements Converter<com.google.cloud.Timestamp, LocalDateTime> {

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public LocalDateTime convert(com.google.cloud.Timestamp timestamp) {
    return Instant
        .ofEpochSecond(timestamp.getSeconds(), timestamp.getNanos())
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
        .toLocalDateTime();
  }
}
```

```java
  @Bean
  public SpannerEntityProcessor spannerConverter(SpannerMappingContext mappingContext) {
    return new ConverterAwareMappingSpannerEntityProcessor(mappingContext,
        List.of(new LocalDateTimeWriteConverter()),
        List.of(new LocalDateTimeReadConverter()));
  }
```

**DB value:** 2020-06-18T15:55:09.000Z
**Actual value:** 2020-06-18T18:55:09.000Z
**Expected value:** 2020-06-18T15:55:09.000Z

How can I override a default Spanner converter?

Comment: Have you looked already at these answers? The last link is a fixed thread on github.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071133/timestamp-converter-not-working-in-spring-data-rest-with-spanner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136904/unable-to-convert-java-sql-timestamp-to-com-google-cloud-timestamp-in-spring-dat https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/pull/2065

Comment: Hi, @AntonioRamirez! Yep, I've looked at those topics. They are a little bit about another. My issue is converting between `com.google.cloud.Timestamp` and `java.time.LocalDateTime`. Spring Data already has a default converter and I need to override it.

Comment: Are you setting the params in the proper order? I mean, when consuming the method?

Comment: [Dmitry S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461728/dmitry-s) posted in an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64761713/12695027) that "I created a fix for this issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/pull/2580"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/pull/2580 which is a fix made by [Dmitry S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461728/dmitry-s) as they mentioned in their [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64761713).

Comment: If I was able to persuade someone to un-delete the original Answer, would you be happy accepting that one and removing this Answer of your?